# Ubuntu wont make it to login screen after switching to gdm

Tags: 14.04

I am having some issues logging into Ubuntu. I am very worried and hope someone here can help. First of all, I came into work this morning and noticed that my computer would not let me login. It was an endless cycle, I would login, screen would go black, and then I would be back at the login screen.

Then I went to this thread:

[Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

However,

this has made things worse. I followed this advice:

Change to another login screen.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to open a terminal.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to go back to the graphic mode.

Type `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm`

In a graphic screen, select gdm and OK.

Type `sudo reboot`

Now I cannot even get to the login screen. It just goes black. I wanted to undo the gdm graphics thing, but I cannot get back to the terminal to do so.

Any help?

Comment: Let me clarify, when I try control+alt+f3, login screen comes up for 2 seconds, then disappears before I can login

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use the Gnome Desktop Environment? If not you might just try switching back from gdm to lightdm and see if it at the very least gets your system back to a usable state.

Comment: I switched back and now at usable state. Can you check out my most recent question (still having login issue but can see login screen at least)

Comment: How did you "switch back"?